Getting Error using Firebase SDK in Android App
I am getting compatibility issues with Kotlin and Gradle whenever I am using Firebase in my App.
The main problem I think is arising from the use of Firestore.
These are the Flutter Dependencies I am using-
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.1 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  firebase_auth: ^4.18.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.15.10
  firebase_storage: ^11.6.11
  firebase_core: ^2.27.2
  json_theme: ^6.4.1
  flutter_carousel_widget: ^2.2.0
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  youtube_player_flutter: ^9.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
  pinput: ^4.0.0
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.2+1
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
  lottie: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:  
  uses-material-design: true


This is my Android Level Gradle File
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23' // Updated Kotlin version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.23"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


This is my Project Level Gradle File
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.the_mbbs_planet"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.{app_name}"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}




flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-java:16.2.0-beta02'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}




This is my Project Level gradle File
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

include ":app"


This is the Debug Console -
C:/Users/Sujas/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/7bdcfdb69654c2696c8a4d27b6f2119e/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.6.2-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 8s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                     │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then │
│ update C:\Users\Sujas\AndroidStudioProjects\the_mbbs_planet\android\build.gradle:          │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                    │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


This is the build output using ./gradlew clean and then ./gradlew build --stacktrace
WARNING:We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (7.3.0) was tested up to compileSdk = 33

This warning can be suppressed by adding
    android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=34
to this project's gradle.properties

The build will continue, but you are strongly encouraged to update your project to
use a newer Android Gradle Plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34

> Task :firebase_app_check:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.appcheck" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_app_check-0.2.2+1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :firebase_auth:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.auth" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_auth-4.19.1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :cloud_firestore:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.16.1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :firebase_storage:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.storage" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_storage-11.7.1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :firebase_core:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\firebase_core-2.29.0\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :flutter_inappwebview_android:processDebugManifest
package="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview_android" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_inappwebview_android-1.0.13\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :smart_auth:processDebugManifest
package="fman.ge.smart_auth" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :path_provider_android:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider_android-2.2.4\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :sqflite:processDebugManifest
package="com.tekartik.sqflite" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\sqflite-2.3.3\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :url_launcher_android:processDebugManifest
package="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\url_launcher_android-6.3.1\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via a source AndroidManifest.xml's package attribute is deprecated.
Please instead set the namespace (or testNamespace) in the module's build.gradle file, as described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-namespace
This migration can be done automatically using the AGP Upgrade Assistant, please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

> Task :firebase_core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :cloud_firestore:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :firebase_app_check:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :firebase_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
3 warnings

> Task :firebase_storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :flutter_inappwebview_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
3 warnings

> Task :path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :sqflite:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :url_launcher_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Task :smart_auth:compileDebugKotlin
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\AppSignatueHelper.kt: (40, 75): 'GET_SIGNATURES: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\AppSignatueHelper.kt: (40, 91): 'signatures: Array<(out) Signature!>!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (13, 52): 'HintRequest' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (118, 22): 'CredentialPickerConfig' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (144, 13): 'Credentials' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (144, 45): 'getHintPickerIntent(HintRequest): PendingIntent' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (157, 34): 'Credentials' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (158, 28): 'save(Credential): Task<Void!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (189, 33): 'CredentialRequest' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (199, 32): 'CredentialsClient' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (199, 52): 'Credentials' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (200, 27): 'request(CredentialRequest): Task<CredentialRequestResponse!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (203, 37): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (232, 33): 'CredentialsClient' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (232, 53): 'Credentials' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (233, 28): 'delete(Credential): Task<Void!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (293, 29): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (293, 48): 'getParcelableExtra(String!): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (293, 67): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (319, 29): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (319, 48): 'getParcelableExtra(String!): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (319, 67): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (330, 45): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (343, 87): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (355, 26): 'Credential' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (355, 37): 'Builder' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (419, 53): 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (469, 53): 'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
w: C:\Users\Sujas\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\smart_auth-2.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\fman\ge\smart_auth\SmartAuthPlugin.kt: (474, 44): 'getParcelable(String?): T?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

> Task :smart_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: [options] source value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 8 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
3 warnings

> Transform debug (project :firebase_core) with DexingNoClasspathTransform
ERROR:C:\Users\Sujas\AndroidStudioProjects\the_mbbs_planet\build\firebase_core\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_dir\debug\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\GeneratedAndroidFirebaseCore$FirebaseAppHostApi$1.class: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "<parameter1>" is null

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin
e: C:/Users/Sujas/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/30c92d1b3ef92e5ce5515d7fc76b9153/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-21.6.2-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTasexecution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(AbstractSkipEmptyWorkStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.HandleStaleOutputsStep.execute(HandleStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:289)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignMutableWorkspaceStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ChoosePipelineStep.execute(ChoosePipelineStep.java:23)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.lambda$execute$2(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)    
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:127)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:116)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
175 actionable tasks: 170 executed, 5 up-to-date


I am using Latest Android Studio (Iguana) and using Kotlin Plugin 1.9.23 and also Latest Gradle 8.7 till date.
I would really appreciate your help.
